# What does Kotlin ?: return expression means

Tags: kotlin, return

i want to know about the expression

```
val videoCapture = this.videoCapture ?: return
```

especially,

```
?: return
```

part.

As far as i know "?" is used for let the variable can be assigned with null.
However i cant really find the explanation related with "?: return" expression.
I found this expression in google camera basic guide in kotlin.
In case you need more code to figure it out.

```
 private fun captureVideo() {
    val videoCapture = this.videoCapture ?: return

    viewBinding.videoCaptureButton.isEnabled = false

    val curRecording = recording
    if (curRecording != null) {
        // Stop the current recording session.
        curRecording.stop()
        recording = null
        return
    }
```

If anyone knows what ?: return means, please kindly guide me.
Thanks.

Comment: Specifically, in your code example, it assigns `this.videoCapture` to the local variable `videoCapture` only if `this.videoCapture` does not reference `null`, otherwise it simply returns from the function (i.e., the rest of the function is "skipped").

Comment: @Slaw After reading the url you gave me, now i get it. I was really obsessed with the ? means that variable can be null in kotlin thanks for your info!

Comment: You might also want to check out [Null safety | Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html).

Comment: @Slaw Its perfect document that resolves my question! Thanks a million.